# SQLAlchemy ForeignKey with dynamic PostgreSQL Schema

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How might one use SqlAlchemy dynamic schema translation with foreign key relationships using the declarative ORM? Below is an example, of what I am trying to do for a multi-tenant DB (each 'user' mapping to a schema). I am not sure how one goes about setting ForeignKey constraints in SQLAlchemy

Assuming the following table declarations:

```
class BaseMixin():
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'dynamic'}

class Image(Base, BaseMixin):
    __tablename__ == 'image'    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

class Point(Base, BaseMixin):
    __tablename__ == 'point'
    fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("image.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

The Point table has a FK relationship to the Image table. I am getting the following error when I attempt to query these tables:

`NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'point.fk' could not find table 'image' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

The session is parametrized with the following:

```
session.connection(execution_options={
                    "schema_translate_map": {"dynamic": "my_custom_schema"}})
```

From the docs, it looks like the schema_translate_map update on the session should be replacing `dynamic` with the user's schema. Oddly, the table instantiation is happening as expected. The error is popping up when attempting to query.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the schema in the `ForeignKey` i.e. update this:

```
    fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("image.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

to:

```
    fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dynamic.image.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```